# Necessity of changing $p$ and $q$ when your private key is exposed?

Tags: rsa, public-key, attack

Suppose your private key $d_1$ has been exposed. Instead of changing $p$ and $q$, instead you just choose a new public and private key (say $e_2$ and $d_2$) and use these instead. What kinds of attacks could someone perform knowing $N,e_1,e_2,d_1$ (where $e_1$ is the first public key)?

Answer (score 2):

If you know even a single key pair $(e,d)$, then [you can factor $N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12328/rsa-fast-factorization-of-n-if-d-and-e-are-know), so that's pretty much the ultimate attack — efficient, total key recovery. For a short, digestible proof of this, see the last fact on page three of Dan Boneh's [*Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem*](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf).

Comment: As an additional info: A. May published "Computing the RSA secret key is deterministic polynomial time equivalent to factoring", which shows that you don't even need a probabilistic algorithm (like the one in Boneh's paper). So yeah, if $d$ is compromised, the factorization is no longer safe.